# concorde with Apple Silicon M1

Tags: c, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I am trying to [install concorde](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/index.html) linked with [QSOPT](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ebico/qsopt/beta/index.html) following [these instructions](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde/DOC/README.html). Regarding QSOPT, I dowloaded files from section Intel MacOS 10.6 (64-Bit). But, as I have Apple M1 chip, it does not work. I think that the problem is in the arm64 architecture in terms of QS, however with other more commercial software for Intel processor, I do not face any issue thanks to Rosetta.

The error I am facing when I run

```
./configure --host=darwin --with-qsopt=fullpath/QS
```

is

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [concorde] Error 1
```

<sub>[Cross-posted](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6446/concorde-with-apple-silicon-m1) on Stack Exchange - Operation Research</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the support of Bill Cook, it is now available a version of `qsopt.a` for the M1 Apple Chip on the [QSOPT download page](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ebico/qsopt/downloads/downloads.htm). This perfectly worked for me by run

`./configure --host=darwin --with-qsopt=fullpath/QS`